# ImageCropper.Forms fails at initialization

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use ImageCropper.Forms, I have followed all steps but it fails in initialization and throws  this exception:

`` Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile> Plugin.Media.Abstractions.IMedia.TakePhotoAsync(Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions) ``

As you can see below, I'm doing all the steps recommended by oficial page: https://github.com/westito/ImageCropper.Forms

AndroidManifest

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/favicon96_96">
        <!-- Image cropper activity -->
        <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
  ...
```

MainActivity

```
Stormlion.ImageCropper.Droid.Platform.Init();
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

...

 public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Stormlion.ImageCropper.Droid.Platform.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

CropperPage

```
public CropperPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Init();
        }

        async void Init()
        {
            
            new ImageCropper()
            {
                PageTitle = "Cut an image",
                AspectRatioX = 1,
                AspectRatioY = 1,
                CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                SelectSourceTitle = "Select a file",
                TakePhotoTitle = "Take a picture",
                PhotoLibraryTitle = "Pic gallery",
                Success = (imageFile) =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        imageView.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    });
                }
            }.Show(this);
       }
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi , remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have to install package ImageCropper.Forms.Fix from Nuget and everything starts to work as expected.